# Does QString::fromUtf8 automatically reverse a Hebrew string?

Tags: qt, utf-8

I am having a problem where a Hebrew string is being displayed in reverse. I use QTableWidget to display some info, and here the string appears correctly using:


 `CString hebrewStr; hebrewStr.ToUTF8(); 

 QString s = QString::fromUtf8( hebrewStr );`

In another part of my program this same string is displayed on the screen, but not using QT, and this is what is being shown in reverse:


`CString hebrewStr; 

hebrewStr.ToUTF8();`

I have debugged and hebrewStr.ToUTF8() in both cases produces the exact same unicode string, but the string is only displayed correctly in the QTableWidget. So I am wondering if Qt automatically reverses a given Hebrew string (since it is a rigth-to-left language). Thanks!

Comment: Right-to-left is more of a rendering issue. I don't think it affects the storage at all (I may be wrong here).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case `QString` generate the full unicode `wchar_t` from the [UTF-8 encoded string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). If you would like to do similar thing in MFC, you should use `CStringW` and decode the string.

[Use `MultiByteToWideChar` for UTF8 to CStringW conversion.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[Connected question in StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318481/utf-8-cstring-and-cfile-c-mfc)